# How do you return an array of string ids using a factory in MirageJS?

Tags: javascript, miragejs

In MirageJS I am trying to create a factory for a simple array model.

#### Current code

Here is my code:

```
  let server = new Server({
    models: {
      usertab: Model
    },

    factories: {
      usertab: Factory.extend( function(i) { return i } ),
    },

    seeds(server) {
      server.createList("tab", 3)
    },

    routes() {
      this.get("api/usertabs", (schema) => {
        return schema.usertabs.all()
      })
    }
    
})
```

#### Current result

The above code returns a list of objects with an `id` key under the `usertabs` key:

```
{ 
  usertabs: [
    {id: "1"},
    {id: "2"},
    {id: "3"},
  ]
}
```

#### Wanted Result

I want to seed the array with simple incrementing numbers so the return value when using `GET api/usertabs` will return:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

For some reason there is no api documentation for `Factory` only a guide. The only examples I could find are ones that create arrays of objects.

Comment: you can convert the usertabs object to array, `return schema.usertabs.all().map(u => u.id)`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath good idea! Although, I wonder if there is a more generic way using the `Factory` class.

Comment: if you store any entity in schema.db, id will be added to that entity; id works like a primary key to facilitate further crud operations like edit,delete etc.

If you are not required to maintain state you can simple return an array, do not store in in db

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.get("api/usertabs", (schema) => {
        return schema.db.usertabs.map(item => item.id);
      })
```

will return an array in stead of an object containing an array.
it is described in more detail here: https://miragejs.com/docs/main-concepts/database/